# How to study analytically this ODE?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I have tried to find some known ODEs before posting on this forum, but I did not find anything about this kind of ODE:

$y'(x)^2 + a(x)*y(x)^2 = 1$

with $a\in C^∞(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and $y\in C^∞(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$

Can anyone give me some advices to find an analytical solution of this ODE and to find its existence and uniqueness?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by "analytical"?

Comment: Is there a general solution of this ODE?

Comment: The situation becomes more tangible if $a(x)$ itself obeys a differential equation (possibly in terms of $y$). Do you have any structural information on $a(x)$?

Comment: What is * in your ODE? Is this multiplication sign?

Comment: @Frits Veerman: we know a and it depends on y. However, if we want to express a with y, we will introduce a second unknow that we can not remove. I can write the expression of the function a, if you want.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko: yes, this is a multiplication sign.

Answer (score 4):

The change $y=w(x\int\sqrt{a(x)}dx)$ reduces to $w'^2+w^2=1/a(x)$.
This is entry 1.370 in Kamke. Kamke gives a further change of the variable
that reduces this to the Abel equation of the form $v'=P_3(x,v),$
where $\deg_vP_3=3$. Abel's equation does not have any
reasonable closed form solution (whatever you mean by the "closed form").

Reference: E. Kamke. Differentialgleichungen. Losungsmethoden und Losungen,I.
Gewohnliche Differentialgleichungen. 6-th edition, Leipzig 1959.

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt that there is a closed-form general solution.  Even in the simple case
$a(x) = x$, Maple finds no closed-form solution and no symmetries.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I would have checked for this simple case.